# Account from another domain is unable to access list, yet it can view the list's item

Tags: 2007, permissions

We're currently preparing a MOSS site for migration to another AD domain. When testing a account of another domain

1. The account was granted Full Control rights, and it can access the site
2. However, the account is unable to access one particular list, while it can access other lists. The said list inherits permission from the site in number 1
3. But the said account can view details of all items of the problematic list in number 2

What should I be looking to determine the cause of issue? So far I'm wondering why the said list didn't inherit permission from the parent site.

**Update**

I ran the following code

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")

function Get-SPWeb([string]$url) {
     $SPSite = Get-SPSite $url
     return $SPSite.OpenWeb()
     $SPSite.Dispose()
}

function Get-SPSite([string]$url) {
     New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($url)
}

$web = Get-SPWeb "url to the list"
$list = $web.Lists["NameOfList"]
$permInfo = $list.GetUserEffectivePermissionInfo("AnotherDomain\Account")
```

I got the following result

```
Permissions
----------
FullMask 

Member                           RoleDefinitionBindings          Parent
------                           ----------------------          ------
AnotherDomain\Account            {Full Control}
NT AUTHORITY\authenticated users {Contribute, Read, Limited Access}
Site Owners                      {Full Control, Limited Access}
Site Members                     {Contribute, Limited Access}
```

The way i see the permission list, there should be no issue at all

**Update 2**

I checked the permission set up and I noticed that Limited Access, implying some list has different permission set up. What we did is back up and restore production copy to the site and it worked. I suspected that the permission of the site is in bad shape.

Comment: Have you made sure that the user has the exact permissions in Number 2 as in Number 1 after the migration?

Comment: However, the list inherts permission from the parent site, and the said account is granted full control on the parent site.